# How can I save XGboost base_learners?

Tags: python, multithreading, xgboost

I am learning an ensemble model using XGBoost algorithm

When I printed base_learners, it seems to be stored as a dictionary type.
like this :

```
{'dnn': <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000001BB50B97C88>, 'random forest': RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=4, max_features='sqrt', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=2, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1,
            oob_score=False, random_state=42, verbose=0, warm_start=False), 'extra trees': ExtraTreesClassifier(bootstrap=False, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
           max_depth=4, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
           min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
           min_samples_leaf=2, min_samples_split=2,
           min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=-1,
           oob_score=False, random_state=42, verbose=0, warm_start=False)}
```

To use 'base_learner' in another file, How can I save that?
I can't use save_model(). because that is not model

And, also I can't using pickle module. I don't know why.

But I think multithreaded error problems.

When I using pickle module, I got the following error message:

```
pickle.dump(base_learners, open('./models/base_learners.pkl', 'wb'))
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using sckit learn library.

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib  
joblib.dump(test_model, "trained-model.pkl")
```

Load the trained model from file

```
test_model = joblib.load("trained-model.pkl")
```

Check if it works. Here Value of test_model is

```
LogisticRegressionCV(Cs=3, class_weight='balanced', cv=10, dual=False,
           fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1.0, max_iter=100,
           multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=-1, penalty='l2', random_state=42,
           refit=False, scoring=None, solver='lbfgs', tol=0.0001,
           verbose=0)
```

Now if it don;t work for you, then you need to take out the value of key "random forest" and "extra trees" and save it as pickle files. I just tried comparing this value with my value and both looks similar format. Once, you can reload both values , you can recreate your original base_learners.